# Renaming A Plist In Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, plist, rename

I want to rename a plist file in Objective-C which is used to save data. Here is how I defined the path for the plist file:

```
- (NSString *)save {
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [[path objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"save.plist"];
}
```

How can I rename this file? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/moveItemAtPath%3atoPath%3aerror%3a)  `moveItemAtPath:toPath:error:` method.

```
NSError *error;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] movePath:oldPath toPath:newPath error:&error];
```

For Example:

```
NSArray *path =
NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *oldPath =  [[path objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"save.plist"];

NSString *newpath = [[path objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"new.plist"];
```

Answer (score 0):

so you have a plist file in an xcode project and you want to rename it? what is stopping you just renaming it in the project navigator?

**EDIT:**

if the plist is generated dynamically, then just load the plist and save it again with the new name.

Comment: It's in his app's documents directory.